# C# data convert to xml

Tags: c#, xml, json

I have some data retrieved from web in following format (in a stream):

```
{"parts":[
{"title":"Heading1","logo":"http:\/\/asd.com\/3.png","date":{"d":"24","m":"01","y":"2012"},
"blocks":[
    [
    {"time":"01:23","link":"http:\/\/google.com","title":"titleName1","info":"someinfo...","image":"http:\/\/url22.jpg","is_ended":true,"is_active":false,"description":"","description1":"","description2":""},
    {"time":"01:24","link":"","title":"titleName2","info":"","image":"http:\/\/asd.as\/6.jpg","is_ended":true,"is_active":false,"description":"","description1":"","description2":""},
    {"time":"05:25","link":"","title":"titleName2","info":"someinfo","image":"http:\/6.jpg","is_ended":false,"is_active":false,"description":"","description1":"","description2":""}
    ]
    ]
}
]
}
```

Now I need to get this to XML format or any decent format to work with. 
Is this data in any standard format?

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called JSON.
You can use [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (available on NuGet) to parse it.